# Bootstrap datatable header and column not same

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, datatable

I have used bootstrap server-side data table in my PHP project it works like a charm but my problem is with the last column of table separate border, it's not showed I don't know why

The other problem with data table in print page, the header of columns not same with the column.

1. last column separate border not show:

[image]

2. In print view column and header not same:
   [image]

Html code:

```
<table class="table table-bordered cell-border" width="100%" cellspacing="0" id="patientsReport">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="text-center">تاریخ</th>
                            <th class="text-center">نام</th>
                            <th class="text-center">وضیت روحی</th>
                            <th class="text-center">انرژی</th>
                            <th class="text-center">تغذیه</th>
                            <th class="text-center">ورزش</th>
                            <th class="text-center">خستگی</th>
                            <th class="text-center">فعالیت</th>
                            <th class="text-center">خواب</th>
                            <th class="text-center">عوامل تاثیرگذار بر خواب</th>
                            <th class="text-center">سایر علائم</th>
                            <th class="text-center">یادداشت</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
         </table>
```

Javascript code:

```
$('#patientsReport').dataTable({
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'copy',
                titleAttr:'کپی' ,
                text: '<i class="fa fa-files-o"></i>',
                columns: ':visible'
            },
            {
                text: '<i class="fa fa-print"></i>',
                action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                    window.onafterprint = function(){
                        $('.dt-buttons').show();
                    };
                    $('.dt-buttons').hide();
                    window.print();
                }
            },
            {
                extend: 'excel',
                text: '<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i>',
                columns: ':visible'
            },
        ],

        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "paging": false,
        "searching": false,
        "info": false,
        "ordering": false,
        'ajax': '<?php echo $rdr_str ?>',
        'language': {
            url : 'Resources/lang/Persian.json'
        },
        scrollX:        true,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        columnDefs: [

        ],
        fixedColumns: false,
        "columns": [
            { data: "15", },
            { data: "1" },
            { data: "9", visible: <?php echo $chkMental ?> },
            { data: "6", visible: <?php echo $chkEnergy ?> },
            { data: "12", visible: <?php echo $chkNutrition ?> },
            { data: "10", visible: <?php echo $chkSport ?> },
            { data: "7", visible: <?php echo $chkFatigue ?> },
            { data: "11", visible: <?php echo $chkActivity ?> },
            { data: "5", visible: <?php echo $chkSleep ?> },
            { data: "18", visible: <?php echo $chkSleep2 ?> },
            { data: "8", visible: <?php echo $chkOther ?> },
            { data: "17", visible: <?php echo $chkNote ?> },
            // { data: "16" },

        ]
    });
```

Comment: we can't help you; not for what you posted anyway.

Comment: Please share you code by editing your question and then people might be able to try helping you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure include all the resources like dataTables.bootstrap.min.js

1. you can solve border issue by add class.

   `.yourtable_container table, th, td {border: 1px solid #ddd !important; }`

   **or add class to specific coloumn**

   `"columnDefs": [{className: "your-class", "targets": [0]}]`
2. for printview try this option

   `exportOptions: {stripHtml: false}`

   or you can customize printview by your classes like this. also try [header callback](https://datatables.net/reference/option/headerCallback)

   ```
       buttons: [
           {
               extend: 'print',
               exportOptions: {
                   stripHtml: false
               },
               text: '<i class="fa fa-print"></i> Print',
               customize: function (win) {

                   $(win.document.body).find('table')
                           .addClass('compact')
                           .css('font-size', 'inherit');

               }
           }
       ]
   ```

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to add a **html whitespace** in the cell and see if this fixes the issue or it could be related to your 2nd issue.
2. You are using `scrollX: true,`, which actually causes the plugin to create **2 separate tables** for the header and body, and then align them getting the window width.

Sometimes, it can be that the columns of these 2 tables do not match exactly, but there is slightly unequal. But judging from your screenshot, I would say there is a **javascript error** when rendering.

Also, try resizing your browser to see if the columns will get aligned.
If so, you can try to **reload the header after init**:

```
$('#patientsReport').on('init', function(){
     $('#patientsReport').fixedHeader.adjust();
});
```

Comment: "will get aligned. If so, you..."

Comment: @JannesBotis thanks for answered. I solved second problem with change paper size and layout but the problem of first question is up. I realized now the above code is for second image. but it does not matter because first image code as same as above code just data source is difference. I try again when the cells are not empty, again vertical separator not showed for last column.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly Pass There  { data: "15", visible: },{ data: "1",visible: } instead { data: "15", },{ data: "1" },

Answer (score 0):

You can try solution from following link: [Align Data Headings with Column Headings](https://blog.webnersolutions.com/alternative-solution-for-adding-horizontal-scrollbar-to-jquery-datatable)